# Where do I see my google places checkins?

Tags: checkin, google-places-api

I am developing a mobile-web app and I am trying to checkin to a google place.
So I followed the instructions from the [Google Places Api][1].
I got an access token, made a place search request and now I am trying to checkin to a google place. According to google documentation the only things I need to checkin to a google place are :

- sensor (true or false)
- key (my application's API key)
- reference (got from Places Search request)

So I did the described request and the funny thing is that the response I got back was:

```
{
  "status": "OK"
}
```

But I never managed to see and verify that checkin.

I checked to my Google+ account, to my googlemaps, to places.google.com but I didnt have a luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Places API doesn't store your checkins, it only uses checkins to help with ranking. What you should do is have some logic on your server that stores checking locally so you can query that information later as needed.

Comment: skarE, this seems illogical to me. Why does Google accept the check-in, if it does nothing with it? For me it's obvious that Google should store this fact somewhere. So why don't they expose it later via API???

Comment: Google uses check-ins to affect the ranking of results for future queries. From the documentation: (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceCheckins) - "Check-in activity from your application is reflected in the Place search results that are returned - popular establishments are ranked more highly, making it easy for your users to find likely matches.

As check-in activity changes over time, so does the ranking of each Place."

Comment: thank you for clarification... Actually I am the owner of this place, and I would like to know (using the API) how many check-ins happened on particular date (eg. yesterday).

Comment: Google places API does not require the user to be logged in. You can make POST request with proper API KEY  even though the user is not logged in. This suggests that Google does not store any user specific information on their side. They may probably using the data for ranking the places and that too application specific. Not like FourSquare where every check-in across all apps counts.